# Unity doesn't work with Microsoft cognitive SpeechToText iOS SDK

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, speech-to-text, avaudiosession, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Unity 5.3 and the latest MS STT iOS SDK. If I set UnitySetAudioSessionActive(1), the MS STT will give me an error status -  SpeechClientStatus_MicrophoneUnavailable at the second time when I invoke the speech recognition.

The reason that I had to call the UnitySetAudioSessionActive(1) is that after I use the MS speechToText, my IOS application can't play a audio clip without any error. This is the only way I found that I can hear the audio clip again.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by the following 2 steps -

In the method where you start the mic and recognition, add these lines before you call startMicAndRecognition

```
AVAudioSession *  _aSession= [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];   
[_aSession setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
[_aSession setActive:YES error:nil];
MicrophoneRecognitionClient* micClient =  [SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory createMicrophoneClient:(SpeechRecognitionMode_ShortPhrase)
                                                                                 withLanguage:(self.defaultLocale)
                                                                                withPrimaryKey:(self.subscriptionKey)
                                                                                withSecondaryKey:(self.subscriptionKey)
                                                                                withProtocol:(self)];

[micClient startMicAndRecognition];
```

In the method where you get the final message do something like this -

```
[micClient endMicAndRecognition];
UnitySetAudioSessionActive(1);
```